# Vectorize creation of vector containing means corresponding to categorical variable

Tags: r, vectorization

`Data` contain `label` variable and numeric `x` variable, then I calculate mean values of `x` in groups designated by `label`(`means` object is created which we then use as dictionary), then I would like to 
create new vector containing mean values which repeatitions correspond with `label` variable, below example using `for()`, I don't see how could I vectorize it, only possibility seems to be to use `merge` function, questions are :

1. Does `merge` offers benefits of vectorization (my original dataset, have a few milions of observations) ?
2. If not, then is it possible to vectorize creation of `y` ?

My current code is:

```
set.seed(123)

data<-data.frame(label=sample(c("A","B"),10,replace=TRUE),x=rnorm(10))
data
#   label          x
#1      A  1.7150650
#2      B  0.4609162
#3      A -1.2650612
#4      B -0.6868529
#5      B -0.4456620
#6      A  1.2240818
#7      B  0.3598138
#8      B  0.4007715
#9      B  0.1106827
#10     A -0.5558411


means<-aggregate(formula = x~label, data = data, FUN = mean)
means
#  label          x
#1     A 0.27956110
#2     B 0.03327823

for(i in 1:10){
 y[i]=means[which(means[,1]==data[i,1]),2]
}

data<-data.frame(data, y)
data
#   label          x          y
#1      A  1.7150650 0.27956110
#2      B  0.4609162 0.03327823
#3      A -1.2650612 0.27956110
#4      B -0.6868529 0.03327823
#5      B -0.4456620 0.03327823
#6      A  1.2240818 0.27956110
#7      B  0.3598138 0.03327823
#8      B  0.4007715 0.03327823
#9      B  0.1106827 0.03327823
#10     A -0.5558411 0.27956110
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can significantly improve performance using `data.table` or `dplyr` packages

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, y := mean(x), label]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(label) %>%
  mutate(y = mean(x))
```

Or

If you have *only* two labels and *you already created `means` data set*, you could fully vectorize this in base R using indexes

```
with(means, c(x[1], x[2]))[(data$label == "B") + 1]
```

---

As a side note, you mentioned `merge` so with `data.table` you can do very efficient merges on an aggregated data, so lets illustrate on your `means` data

```
means <- aggregate(x ~ label, data, mean)
```

Then you could simply do

```
setkey(setDT(data), label)[means, y := i.x]
```

Which mean: Convert `data` to `data.table` object and key by `label`. The perform a binary join on `means` while pulling only the `x` column and updating `y`

---

Another option is to perform a full join

```
setkey(setDT(means), label) ; setkey(setDT(data), label)
means[data]
```

Comment: I've got additional question, does above appoach will work in the case of massive datasets (10E6 observations) ? I'm using `ff` package to handle it, now it seems I need some other approach to deal with it

Comment: `data.table` is especially designed in order to work with huge data sets. Jut try it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `aggregate` first and then a `for`-loop. Just use `ave` directly:

```
data <- transform(data, y = ave(x, label, FUN = mean))
```

`?ave` lets you compute functions like `mean` by group (similar to `aggregate`) but doesn't aggregate the data to one row per group. That means the length of the output vector (`y`) is the same as the length of the input vector (`x` in this case).

Comment: is it as fast as procedure using `data.table` ?

Comment: @Qbik, no, you can expect data.table to be significantly faster than base R, especially for larger data sets.